# Equivalent to onContentChange for ListFragment?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment

I have a `ListFragment` that might have no items in the listview. I've added the empty view in the xml:

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty"
            android:text="@string/empty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"/>
```

Usually, when using a `ListActivity`, one would do:

```
@Override
public void onContentChanged() {
    super.onContentChanged();

    View empty = findViewById(R.id.empty);
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setEmptyView(empty);
}
```

This will hide/show the empty view depending if the listview has items or not.

What is the equivalent of a `ListActivity.onContentChanged` for a `ListFragment`?

Comment: what are you using it for ?

Comment: None but maybe we can create an observer for it

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick, without the need to override methods or create observers:

```
final View emptyView = view.findViewById(R.id.empty);
getListView().setEmptyView(emptyView);
```